# PDO query fetches empty array on hosting

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get data from mysql. It is working well on XAMPP, localhost. But I move my files to hosting, it can't fetch data.

My query

```
public function get_all()
 {
   $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT categories.*, COUNT(posts.id) as total FROM $this->table 
   INNER JOIN posts on FIND_IN_SET(categories.id,posts.categories) GROUP BY categories.id ORDER 
   by categories.id DESC");
   $query->execute();
   return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

It returns an array very well but on hosting it has returned empty array. How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you checked that the DBMS versions are the same ? Are you sure there is content on the production database ?

Comment: @CédricFrançoys yes mariadb and php version is same

Comment: Run your query on server - in mysql console tool or some tool like phpmyadmin.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to ensure that all your database credentials are intact with that which you configured on your hosting server and test your code. Ensure that all tables are created with values inserted into it.

**Updated Section**

This will provide you with an insight on how to retrieve all the queries. you will need to study the code and make integrations were appropriate. Try and see if it helps.

```
$return_arr = array();

$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT categories.*, COUNT(posts.id) as total FROM $this->table 
   INNER JOIN posts on FIND_IN_SET(categories.id,posts.categories) GROUP BY categories.id ORDER 
   by categories.id DESC");
$query->execute();

// lets assume you want echo json categories, id etc. you can try this below

while($row = $query->fetch()){
 $id = $row['id'];
    $categories = $row['categories'];
    $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
                    "categories" => $categories);
}

// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Try and see if it helps.

Comment: but i need all data not just one

Comment: are you returning the data as json

Comment: no as you can see PDO::FETCH_ASSOC it returns as an array